# Migrating between machines a google generated API token

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-authentication, google-auth-library

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to google sheets in python (hopefully to the same sheet and different worksheets every time). I went over all the tutorials and i know that i need to :

1. Authenticate in google to generate an API key which is stored in `credentials.json` .
2. Use the credentials in the code and it works fine on my machine.

```
    def generate_credentials(self):
        '''
        Retrieves token and generates credentials
        '''
        creds = None
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('./Memory_test/credentials.json', SCOPES)

        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)

        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
        if creds == None:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('./Memory_test/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds =  flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        return creds

    def test_method(self):
        creds = self.generate_credentials()

        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])

        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
        else:
            print('Name, Major:')
            for row in values:
                # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
```

I've managed to do both of these steps on my machine. The problems is when i want to run the code on another machine without generating a new `credentials.json` file. 
When i run the code on the new machine whenever the code is running i'm required to login in to my google account through which i generated the api key.
Any way to work around that ?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible unless you "hardcode" the credentials into the code, which is a very bad practice. How about storing the credentials.json file into a server, and make your APP download it automatically?

Comment: yes that would be best practice, sotring them somewhere else then downloading